# css bug? left is different from right?

Tags: css

Hello i found a very peculiar thing, apparently left is rendered different from right.
see this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hn8At/2/
here is the html

```
<div id="wraper">
    <div id="ribbon_ct">
        <div class="ribbon left"></div>
        <div class="ribbon right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css

```
body{ margin:0; padding:0px; }
#wraper{ width:800px; margin:0 auto; background:#eee;padding-top:500px;}
#ribbon_ct{ width:100%; background:#c00; height:400px; }
.ribbon{background:#0C9; width:30px; height:30px; position:relative;}
.left{float:left;}
.right{float:right;}

.ribbon.left{  left:-30px;}
.ribbon.right{ right:-30px;}
```

I have 2 green squares on either side, one causes a scrollbar, the other does not. You can only scroll the right one into view. any ideas as to why?

Comment: I didn't understand what you're saying....

Comment: As far as i know, 'left: .. px' and 'right: .. px' don't work on position:relative blocks.

Comment: @davey left and right works on relatives..

Comment: That is normal behavior – everything that you place outside of the viewport on the top or left is cut of and can not be reached via scrolling, only content that extends outside on the right or bottom extends the rendering space so that scrollbars are rendered.

Comment: @CBroe - seems like normal behaviour but it's not obvious at all.

Comment: @avrahamcoo, you're right, i was confused with 'position: static;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its absolutely normal.

If an elements overflows the body from the left, it will be hidden, and from the right it will be scrolled.

use `overflow:hidden;` on `#ribbon_ct` if you want the right div to be hidden.

Comment: Hello I do not what the right div to be hidden, I just had no idea there is a difference between left and right.. can you link to a documentation regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Your #ribbon_ct is 800px wide because of `width: 100%` of #wraper and centered.

When you don't give width to his parent (for ex: `body {width:1000px;}`) or widen the viewport  you can't see the left green square, because you positioned `left: -30px;`.

Try your code not in jsfiddle but directly in browser.

And if #wraper was not centered, you can't see left square even when resizing,